# tidy: create key without rowwise()?

Tags: r, dplyr, key, tibble, rowwise

Is there a way to create a `key` without using `rowwise()`?

Any pointer is much appreciated.

```
df <- tibble(grp1=rev(LETTERS[1:5]),grp2=letters[11:15],grp3=LETTERS[1:5],
      value=rnorm(5,10,10))

df %>% rowwise %>% mutate(key=paste(sort(c(grp1, grp2)), collapse="")) %>% ungroup()
```

```
  grp1  grp2  grp3  value             key  
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>             <chr>
1 E     k     A     -3.73984194875213 AE   
2 D     l     B     3.25846392371014  BD   
3 C     m     C     3.62405652088127  CC   
4 B     n     D     6.41520621902784  BD   
5 A     o     E     20.1892413026407  AE
```

Update: the `tibble` contains multiple character vectors, but the `key` should be generated from column `grp1` and `grp3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a vectorized option using `pmin/pmap`.  Take the `min/max` for each row  of columns 'grp1', 'grp3' with `pmin/pmax` and concatenate together (`str_c`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate(key = str_c(pmin(grp1, grp3), pmax(grp1, grp3)))
# A tibble: 5 x 5
#  grp1  grp2  grp3   value key  
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>
#1 E     k     A      24.7  AE   
#2 D     l     B       5.66 BD   
#3 C     m     C      16.3  CC   
#4 B     n     D       5.88 BD   
#5 A     o     E      -9.22 AE
```

#### data

```
df <- tibble(grp1=rev(LETTERS[1:5]),grp2=letters[11:15],grp3=LETTERS[1:5],
          value=rnorm(5,10,10))
```

NOTE: `cbind` converts to `matrix` and matrix can hold only a single class.  By converting to `tibble` with `as_tibble` doesn't change the class automatically.  Instead, use `tibble/data.frame` directly instead of `cbind` route

Comment: Awesome, this is blazing fast! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

using `purrr::pmap_chr` :

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(key=pmap_chr(.[c("grp1","grp3")],~paste(sort(c(...)), collapse="")))
# # A tibble: 5 x 5
#   grp1  grp2  grp3  value             key  
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>             <chr>
# 1 E     k     A     22.0150932758833  AE   
# 2 D     l     B     2.24725610156698  BD   
# 3 C     m     C     -6.2414882455089  CC   
# 4 B     n     D     22.5699168856552  BD   
# 5 A     o     E     -6.21443670571301 AE
```

In base R you could do:

```
transform(df, key=mapply(function(...) paste(sort(c(...)), collapse=""), grp1, grp3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've updated my question... Can this work when you have multiple character vectors/columns and you need to specify which to generate the key from?

Comment: Please avoid changing questions in ways that make answers obsolete, better to update with an additional example

Comment: I apologize for the oversight. Yes, your answer addresses the issue. Thanks a lot, very neat!

Comment: Thanks @Moody_Mudskipper for updating both answers. As it turns out, @AntoniosK's answer is faster on my real data (evaluated using `profvis::profvis()`)

Comment: Interesting, I wouldn't have thought that. They're both looping in R, `pmap_chr` might have more overheads but I'd expect them to converge as size goes up, how big is the data and how big is the difference ?

Comment: I added a way in base R, might be more efficient

Comment: On `df <- as_tibble(cbind(grp1=sample(size=1000,x=rev(LETTERS[1:5]),replace=T),grp2=sample(size=1000,x=letters[11:15],replace=T),grp3=sample(size=1000,x=LETTERS[1:5],replace=T),value=rnorm(1000,10,10)))` Moody_Mudskipper's tidy approach takes 30ms and AntoniosK's tidy approach takes 10ms.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `mutate`, without `rowwise`, but with a vectorised version of your function, like this:

```
library(dplyr)

# create a function and vectorise it
f = function(x, y) paste(sort(c(x, y)), collapse="")
f = Vectorize(f)

# use the function
df %>% mutate(key = f(grp1, grp3))

# # A tibble: 5 x 5
#   grp1  grp2  grp3  value             key  
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>             <chr>
# 1 E     k     A     -4.41213449814982 AE   
# 2 D     l     B     10.4314736952111  BD   
# 3 C     m     C     5.69345098226371  CC   
# 4 B     n     D     4.39266020802413  BD   
# 5 A     o     E     22.0623810028979  AE
```

Comment: Thanks! Very neat!

Comment: @AntoniosK : edited to make compatible with updated question